# Write to file not working after hosting (publishing the web application) ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, file

Writing to a file is not working after hosting the web application, whereas they were working while developing and testing in my localhost on debug mode. What could be the problem in writing to a file after hosting? Is there any special permission that should be given to the folders/file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the OS version or the code you're trying to use, I'd say the most likely culprit is permissions. The ASP.NET user (which varies based on version of Windows) needs write access to the folder you're trying to write to. This is likely not enabled by your host.

Comment: Hi,
How to give permissions?
How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the server (either physically or through remote desktop)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need read, write, and modify permissions to the directory you wish to write to.  You need to ensure that the account under which ASP.NET is running has those rights set up.

Comment: How to do that? I mean, How to give read, werite and Modify permission to the directory? Is there any steps to follow?

Thanks